# Database trigger before insert and Calculations

Tags: mysql, cursor, ddl, database-trigger

So I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `chittytransactions` (
  `ChittyTransactionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AuctionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChittyAccNo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransRefence` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reference from actual Bank transaction',
  `TransStatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If Transaction Pending or Cleared',
  `ClearanceDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaymentMethod` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0- Cash, 1- bank transfer, 2- personal credit etc'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `chittyusers` (
  `ChittyAccNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChittyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LatePaymentFee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `UserNameVerified` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What Im trying to do is check If a transaction date is the same as the cleared date in the `chittytransaction` table and if not add a late payment fee to the `chittyusers` table (preferable to be calculated based on each day a extra fee is added to late payment based on date). This should be done before and insert and I'm using a trigger. So far i have this:

```
ROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS chitty_beforet_trig;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER chitty_beforet_trig BEFORE Insert ON chittytransaction
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  DECLARE `mainDate` datetime;
  DECLARE `claredDate` datetime;
  DECLARE `chitAccNo` INT(11);
  DECLARE `userId` INT(11);
  DECLARE `latePay` DOUBLE;
  DECLARE late TINYINT;
  DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ChittyAccNo FROM accounting.`chittyusers`;
  DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT  `Date` FROM accounting.`chittyTransaction`; 
  DECLARE cursor3 CURSOR FOR SELECT  ClearanceDate FROM accounting.`chittyTransaction`;
  DECLARE cursor4 CURSOR FOR SELECT  UserId FROM accounting.`users`;

  OPEN cursor1;
  OPEN cursor2;
  OPEN cursor3;
  OPEN cursor4;

  FETCH cursor1 INTO chitAccNo;
  FETCH cursor2 INTO mainDate
  FETCH cursor3 INTO claredDate;
  FETCH cursor3 INTO userId;
    CASE
        WHEN claredDated <> mainDate THEN
            SET late ='1';
         ELSE
            SET late = '0';
         END;
    END CASE;

    IF late THEN
        UPDATE `chittyusers` SET LatePaymentFee = 50 WHERE UserId = userId;
    END IF;
 CLOSE cursor1;
 CLOSE cursor2;
 CLOSE cursor3;
 CLOSE cursor4;

 END;;
 DELIMITER;
```

I keep getting many different errors etc ad i don't know if I'm doing it right or not. Never used these before so its a little difficult. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please and any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My goodness, where to begin?

For starters, a row trigger should never query the table to which it is attached. (MySQL will allow this; many DBMSes won't.)

An `INSERT` row trigger always has access to the row being inserted via the **`NEW`** pseudorecord, which contains the same columns as the underlying table. The contents of **`NEW`** are initialized from the `VALUES` clause of the `INSERT` statement, and any changes you make to **`NEW`** will be reflected in the table row once the insert completes.

Another problem is that your cursor on `chittyusers` has an unconditional `SELECT`, which will grab *every* row from the table, not just the one you want. What you're actually doing is grabbing a nearly-random value for `userId` which probably has nothing to do with the one you want. You actually don't even need to use a cursor for this; a simple `INSERT ... INTO` with a `WHERE` clause will work better:

```
SELECT `UserId`
  INTO `userId`
  FROM chittyusers
  WHERE ChittyAccNo = NEW.ChittyAccNo;
```

Third, your CASE structure is superfluous; you can do exactly the same with a simple IF:

```
IF NEW.ClearanceDate <> NEW.`Date` THEN
  UPDATE `chittyusers`
    SET LatePaymentFee = 50
    WHERE UserId = userId;
END IF;
```

I'm not about to write the entire trigger for you, but these pointers should at least get the error messages down to a manageable number.

Comment: Thank you. Figured it out thanks to you. but why is there a problem with using a case?

Comment: There isn't a problem; it just isn't necessary. Scrapping it reduces variables, lines of code, and complexity.

Comment: Am I using it wrong though?. if yes how would i change it?

Comment: It's normally used when your logic has three or more paths to choose from. The [example at the bottom of this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) illustrates that.

Comment: So how can i check if a  day has gone by and do a calculation?

Comment: I would build the `IF` condition around [one of MySQL's date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You can then use the [`IF ... THEN` or `IF ... ELSE` structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) to decide whether (or which) calculations get executed.

Comment: Would the `FROM_DAYS()` add a day to date non-stop?

Comment: It would depend on what exactly you want to do, and might be better posted as a separate question.